# Post comments to a wordpress website from an android app

Tags: android, wordpress, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a wordpress website, for which I was developing an android application. GETing data is pretty easy, as no authentication is required. But posting comments, liking a blog, these actions require authentication. Can someone guide me about how to social login (Google or facebook login) to authenticate and post comments or like a post, through the android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Rest API](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/). You can use it to manipulate data without using web interface at all.
Also there an article about using  [Rest API in Android](https://apppresser.com/using-wordpress-rest-api-mobile-app/)

oauth is pretty simple. You just need to get a token(string) from Google or Facebook and you will use in Rest API.

Comment: Can you show me an example (any link or code snippet if possible) on how to authorize using a google sign in token. There is no android example present in the documentation.